# Using Javascript and Automator and the Mail App in Yosemite - How to make a new email?

Tags: javascript, email, automator, osx-yosemite

I am stumped with the Mac Automator for the Mail App. I am trying to automate sending emails to people, letting them know that mail has arrived at our office.

Since Mountain Lion (I have Yosemite) you can't drag and drop variables into the recipient or body input fields. So, I can't say "Hi [NAME], you have a package." I just have to settle for saying "Hi, you have a package" because as far as I know, I can't use a variable in the body.

Well, that's not good enough for me, so I went searching and found out that in Yosemite, we can use Javascript instead of Applescript. I thought this was the solution, and found this great [tutorial](http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/getting-started-with-javascript-for-automation-on-yosemite/).

But I am struggling still with the basics, like how to create a simple email Message. The way that the Script Editor organizes actions, methods, and calls in the Library is a bit confusing. And there are no examples.

For example, I know how to control the Mail app:

```
mail = Application('Mail);
```

Easy enough, but how do I make a message?

```
message = mail.Message(); //doesn't work
message = new mail.Message(); //doesn't work
message = Message(); //doesn't work
```

And there is confusion because the 'Message' object in the Library is underneath the framework option... how do I access this?

This image is the practice code I'm trying, the Library, and the methods and objects available with the Mail app.

[image: Script Editor, Library, and Library (Mail) Calls]

Can someone explain to me why it says 'Mail' and not 'Mail Suite' and why Messages are under 'Mail Framework' and how do I create a message? This would be a lifesaver!

Thanks so much!

Comment: Could it have something to do with the missing quote in mail = Application('Mail) ?

Comment: Javascript for automator is a big mess. One cannot go back to open a different 'dictionary' (since when are references called dictionaries? let's make everything more complex by thinking of different names for existing concepts! yaay). It's very complicated for experienced javascript developers to start with. I can not find functions (or maybe they are called commands??) in the dictionary that ARE working, apparently:
```Chrome = Application('Google Chrome'); Chrome.activate()``` - works, but there is no .activate() function in the 'Dictionary': worthless. Use something else entirely!

Answer (score 0):

```
var toRecipient = "me@mail.com"
var subject = "My Subject"
var body = "My Body";

var mail = Application("Mail");
var msg = mail.OutgoingMessage().make();

msg.visible = true;
msg.toRecipients.push(mail.Recipient({address: toRecipient}));
msg.subject = subject;
msg.content = body;
//msg.attachments.push(mail.Attachment({ fileName: Path("/Users/me/Desktop/attachment.pdf")}));

mail.activate();
msg.send();
```